# Err.number 4599 when using DDE channels through VBA

Tags: vba

I have a piece of code I've used many times in the past.  I'm now trying it on another computer which has a newer version of office. When I run the code "ddeapp.DDEExecute pChan, command" I get the error run-time error 4599: Process failed in other application.  In this case

```
command =  "wait system; send """ & sendString & """; wait system;"
pChan = 1 (which is the channel number)
ddeapp = instance of MS Word
```

The code is

```
Private Sub pExec(command)
On Error Resume Next
If pChan <> -1 Then
  ddeapp.DDEExecute pChan, command
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    On Error GoTo 0
    pCommError
  End If
End If
End Sub
```

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?